# Error when Loading utf-8 file with petl module in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, etl, codec

```
    import petl as etl

    file_name = 'name of file'
    file_in_memory = etl.fromcsv(file_name, encoding='utf-8')
    print (etl.look(file_in_memory))

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The file contains "20 Rue d'Estrées, 75007 Paris, France" which is causing the error.

I can read the file using codes.open(file_name, mode='r', encoding='utf-8')but want to be able to use the petl library to manipulate the csv easily.

Is there a way I can load this into memory through petl.fromcsv whilst preserving the characters?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to find out the encoding of the file first by using the chardet module. By using the universal detector function it iterates through the contents of the file and returns the encoding based on the characters in the file.

A dictionary is returned with the key 'encoding'.

```
   from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector
   import petl as etl

   detector = UniversalDetector()
   file_open = open(file_name)
   for line in file_open.readlines():
       detector.feed(line)
       if detector.done: break
   detector.close()
   file_open.close()
   file_encoding = detector.result['encoding']

   file_name = 'name of file'
   file_in_memory = etl.fromcsv(file_name, encoding=file_encoding)
   print (etl.look(file_in_memory))
```

The detection of the file encoding could be put into a function if required more than once.